# how to display banner ads codename

Tags: admob, codenameone, display

I am a little bit confused. I try to add banner ads to my application. I created admod ids (one for full page ads and one for banner ads) and defined in the properties dialog via android.googleAdUnitId. What is the next step? Should I now use these ids in AdsService functions? This means for me I should also register in Inneractive?

Answer (score 0):

The next step is that when you send a device build a banner will appear at the bottom of the screen and your form will be slightly smaller to accommodate that ad.

Comment: That's fine I will try it. But there is another question then: I sometimes show the ad banner at the top of my screen and sometimes at the bottom. And depending on the membership status I turn the ads on and off. Is there a possibility to control this. In one answer I saw this not possible, Is that true?

Comment: I think we wanted to add the ability to control it in the past but eventually didn't provide that ability as this was challenging on Android.

Comment: FYI there are several other ways to show ads on Codename One by using cn1libs: https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

Comment: Shai; 
thanks for your answers and guidance. Now I have a black banner on in my application but no ads.

As I looked there are other solutşons for ads but as far as I can see only for fullscreen ads.

Comment: I've communicated with my team mates who deal more with ads and they say that banner ads just aren't used much as they provide very poor return so we had no major demand for it. Googling for Androids admob black rectangle came up with answers like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947115/admob-the-banner-shows-a-black-background-and-no-ad which might indicate the solution (publisher ID or testing mode)