# Ionic 2 banner is not visiable after publishing on play store?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic2

Ionic 2 banner is not visiable after publishing on play store. Its just a black box bottom of the screen.
Not sure what is the problem

```
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { // for android & amazon-fireos
          console.log('in here');
          this.admobid = {
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-3767919174603479/5466077284'
          };
        }

        if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner({
          adId: this.admobid.banner,
          position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
          autoShow: true
        });
```

Comment: No body is there...... :(